# Embedding of weighted Lebesgue space on Fourier side into $C^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Given $g$, a continuous real-valued function defined in $\mathbb R^n$,

$K^g:=\{u:e^g \hat{u}\in L^2(\mathbb R^n,(1/2 \pi)^nd \xi)\}$.

Thus $K^g$ can be viewed as a Hilbert space with natural norm $||u||_{K^g}=||e^g\hat{u}||_{L^2(\mathbb R^n,(1/2 \pi)^nd \xi)}$

Prove that if

$g(\xi)/\log(1+|\xi|)$ tends to $\infty \quad$ as $|\xi|\rightarrow \infty$,

then $K^g$ is continously embedded in $C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$

---

Here is my attempt:

If suffices to show $\forall$ compact $F$ and nonnegative integer $m$,

$\quad \Sigma_{|\alpha|\le m}\max_{x \in F}|D^{\alpha} u(x)| \le C_{m,F}||u||_{K^g}$, where $C_{m,F}$ is a nonnegative constant depending only on F and m. $\quad $With the help of Fourier inverse formula, what I have in mind is

$\quad \max_{x \in \mathbb R^n}|D^{\alpha} u(x)| \le ||\space|\xi|^{\alpha}|\hat{u}(\xi)|\space||_{L^1(\mathbb R^n, (1/2 \pi)^nd \xi)}$.

I also realized that $e^{g(\xi)}=(1+|\xi|)^{A(\xi)}$, where $A(\xi)=g(\xi)/\log(1+|\xi|)\rightarrow \infty$ as $\xi \rightarrow \infty$.

My problem is that I cannot deal with the case $|\xi|$ is not large enough.

---

I'm not sure whether I am in the right direction. Any comment or answer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only large frequencies matter for smoothness. For every $M$, the part of Fourier transform with $\{\xi:|\xi|\le M\}$ contributes a *real-analytic* term to the function.

You know that integrability of $|\xi|^\alpha \hat u(\xi)$ implies certain smoothness of $u$. So you want to show that this product is integrable for every $\alpha$. On every ball $\{|\xi|\le M\}$ it is integrable simply because 
$$
\int_{|\xi|\le M}|\xi|^\alpha |\hat u(\xi)|   
\le M^\alpha \sqrt{\int_{|\xi|\le M}|\hat u(\xi)|^2 \int_{|\xi|\le M}|\xi|^{2\alpha} } <\infty
$$ 
 On the set $|\xi|\ge M$ you have your comparison, where $|\xi|^\alpha$ gets dominated  by $e^g$.

Comment: Actually I want to show this inequality, $\quad \Sigma_{|\alpha|\le m}\max_{x \in F}|D^{\alpha} u(x)| \le C_{m,F}||u||_{K^g}$,  so although  integrability of $|\xi|^α \hat{u}(ξ)$ may be true, it doesn't prove the embedding property.

Comment: @user167839 Okay, but since  $e^g$ is positive,  continuous, and grows at infinity, it is bounded from below by a positive constant. So, the $L^2$ norm of $e^g \hat u$ controls the $L^2$ norm of $\hat u$, which was used above to control the contribution of bounded frequencies.

Comment: Thanks. I just messed up with some constants and confused about what depends what.